# Why does the html template in django display all possible messages of incorrect input before I even tried to input something?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I implemented django user authentication following [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html)

here is my html template:

```
{% block title %}Регистрация{% endblock %}
{% block additional_content %}
   <p class="scheise">Регистрация</p> 
        {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class = "sgnupform">
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>

  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

here is my class-based view:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

yet somewhy messages indicative of incorrect input are displayed firsthand, before I even entered anything into a user form, and before I hit "enter":
    [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class = "sgnupform">
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
       {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
    {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>

  </div>
```

try this, as you are displaying the errors directly and not after post

Comment: the error messages disappeared, but so did the input fields
http://i.imgur.com/e412wA7.png

Comment: i am sorry, i thought you would be adding the fields, i just gave the error part, anyways have edited the ans, you can check now

Comment: no, I checked both versions, the previous one and this, with added fields after edition - now it's as the same
http://imgur.com/yLfZjLJl.png
but don't worry, I figured it out how it should be
http://imgur.com/aQ4Hvcrl.png
Thanx, anyway